# Difference between tie and cravat

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I wonder if the words tie and cravat (they translate to the same word in German) are completely interchangeable or if there are some subtle differences to a native speaker.

Comment: Google Images would be your friend here. picture == 1k words. [Tie](https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=off&hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1133&bih=1192&q=tie&oq=tie&gs_l=img.3..0l10.1591.1983.0.2717.3.3.0.0.0.0.20.38.3.3.0.msedr...0...1ac.1.61.img..0.3.37.z1VMzX0XrU0) /  [Cravat](https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=off&hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1133&bih=1192&q=cravat&oq=cravat&gs_l=img.3..0l10.1591.1983.0.2717.3.3.0.0.0.0.20.38.3.3.0.msedr...0...1ac.1.61.img..0.3.37.z1VMzX0XrU0)

Comment: @Tetsujin great idea. Sometimes you just don't come up with such an easy solution ;-) Want to put it in an answer?

Comment: I think Stephie's pretty much nailed it. Just think of a tie as going with a business suit etc, a cravat would be more 'theatrical' - wider, flouncier, open neck as well as closed.

Comment: I've never heard of a cravat before! Although I can see from the pictures that it's different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Historically both items of clothing originate from a piece of cloth that was wound around a rider's neck. The name stems from Croatian mercenaries. Over time, it became a fashionable item with cravats (and their dozens of ways of tying them) being one symbol of dandyism in the Regency era. This explains why the term "cravat" (-> Krawatte in German) can be found in many languages.

Over time, the cravat - a wider piece of cloth, more resembling a shawl - has "slimmed down" to a small strip of fabric and changed the name in English to "tie", denoting the act of knotting them around the wearer's neck. A special form of tie is a bow-tie. In German, there exists the equivalent term "Binder", but it has never really replaced "Krawatte".

And just for the sake of completeness: In German (and sometimes in English) a cravat could also be called a "Plastron".

Comment: I would be careful about using the term "plastron", as it's pretty obscure, and also means things like [the underside shell of a turtle](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/463796/plastron) (which is actually the only sense found in the Encyclopedia Britannica) and [a piece of protective gear for fencing](http://www.leonpaulusa.com/acatalog/Plastrons_Chest_Protectors.html).

Comment: As the Collins dictionary (http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tie?showCookiePolicy=true) lists 12 meanings for the noun "tie", I am convinced my fellow readers will also be able to differenciate between a turtle and a piece of cloth.

Comment: Yes, I'm just saying it's super-obscure.  "Cravat" is more obscure than "tie", and "plastron", particularly when it refers to neckwear, is about a mile more obscure than either of those.

Answer (score 4):

This is a tie:

[image]

It is quite narrow and you can make a small knot in the top.

This man's wearing a cravat:

[image]

A cravat is much wider and you can't put a small knot at the top. It is half like a tie and half like a scarf.

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: It is indeed helpful, thanks! Now it's kind of hard to choose between yours and Stephies answer...

Comment: Glad it was helpful! You can give the green ticky thing to Stephie. Their answer is a good interesting answer! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the compliment. I like the simplicity of your answer- probably better in a multi-language setting. I choose to add a bit of background to address OP's native language where tie=Krawatte.