# Is a plastron correctly defined as a neck-tie?

Tags: definition

I had never heard of this word, and I'm suspicious that this is really its correct meaning.

As far as I can see the etymology leads from Greek roots to chest protection to the front decorative panel of a bodice.

Equestrian female clothing which required a stock tie to worn (as it would double as a bandage for horse or rider) appears to have caused a confusion with the plastron of the bodice that continues in dressage uniform where a stock tie serves the same function of both (though probably used less often as a bandage).

It seems to me that the usage of the word plastron for a neck-tie comes from this confusion through the popularity of equestrian sports.

Plastron so far as I can see is really the panel under the stock tie, and not the tie itself.

Can anyone correct my amateur sleuthing, and explain how the meaning came to be or is etymology unimportant if it is widely (if infrequently) used?

Comment: Where have you found a definition (or a use) of it as a necktie? Please provide a reference for that specific sense.

Comment: The iWeb corpus has 914 hits for "plastron". I've only looked at 214 of them, but in that selection, the overwhelming majority are about turtles or other animals, and a significant minority are about fencing wear. I noticed a single one which referred to clothing (other than for fencing), and that one clearly means the panel in the front of a bodice.

Comment: I came across the term while researching formal dress, in dress codes and clothing etiquette. Often these guides would be written in fairly broken English but it made me wonder what this type of tie was. This curiosity led to this forum, https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48870/difference-between-tie-and-cravat/48874#48874

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This use seems really odd to me ... *however*, you never know what obscure niche market will coin its own jargon to describe the kind of items they sell.  In this case it does seem a ["plastron necktie"](https://www.etsy.com/market/plastron_tie) is a real thing.

There seems to be two flavors.  Either it's a necklace with a large decorative frontpiece:

[image] [image]

or it's a kind of short, broad tie, apparently used in equestrian events, to fill in the space between the chin and the riding jacket (similar to a [*cravat*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cravat)):

[image][image]

There seem to be a number of styles of this latter type, with some called a "pzazz", especially where one end crosses over the other end:

[image]

All of these are related to the general definition of "plastron" to refer to something that "covers the chest", although these are clearly decorative, not protective.

Comment: Great answer, thank you for the time that you took to make it. But it seems to me that while something as a cravat can be very similar to a plastron, there is a real difference in that cravat is tied around the neck, and the plastron in attached to the chest, The exception being in equestrian dress where the tie/plastron have become combined into a single item. I do feel though that to use plastron as another word for tie is wrong, and arises from a misunderstanding of what a stock tie/plastron is.

Comment: @TijgerHaai  Actually it seems a "plastron" is worn around the neck.  It looks like you tie it in a similar way as you would a typical necktie.  As for whether "plastron" is *correct:* ... well, it's what the equestrians call it, and it seems to have been in use for some time, so if you were to describe it with other equestrians it would make sense to use their nomenclature.  If you are a part of that community there are certainly hundreds of other equestrian-specific terms you'd also need to know, like "snaffle" and "crop".

Comment: It is my interpretation that the current dressage plastron, is really a stock tie/plastron combination, and the stock has merely fallen away in usage. It is the stock tie that goes around the neck. But even given the exception of equestrians, it is a very specific term and not something that can be generalised to all neck ties, or even any other category of neck ties. But thanks alot for your input, helps show I'm not completely wrong in my interpretations.